# Entity Framework 6.0 not showing newly added SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Entity Framework 6.0 in VS 2015 using a code-first approach. When I am adding a new model and migrate it, it's showing in `DbContext` and I am able to access it.

The problem is when I write a SQL query to create table (I don't need model for this because it is static data which is never going to be changed). After the `update-database` command, it's not showing up in context. If I create model and execute migrate command it is showing.

How to create a SQL Server table via query and access it in `DbContext` *without* creating models for it? Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like "SQL first", I don't think there is much support for that in EF. You may have to fall back to ADO.NET.

Comment: You **cannot** do that - if you use code-first approach, unless you have a model class and a `DbSet<OfThatModelClass>`  in your context, that table is invisible to EF ....